# Tab completion inside singularity bash shell

Tags: tab-completion, linux-containers, singularity-container

I am using a singularity container created from a docker ubuntu:xenial base image. When I get into the shell using this command -

```
singularity shell --bind /path/to/inputs:/mnt3,/path/to/outputs:/mnt2 /singularity_docker_xenial_image.img
```

1) the tab completion does not work
2) arrow keys produce strange characters

For example typing **ls[tab][up][down][left][right]** produces this -

```
singularity_docker_xenial_image.img> $ ls   ^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C
```

Does anybody know 1) why tab completion doesn't work and 2) why the strange characters are produced?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must install singularity with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/singularityware/singularity.git

cd singularity

git fetch --all

git checkout 2.6.0

./autogen.sh

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --sysconfdir=/etc

make

sudo make install
```

1. tap competition

   if you install singularity without **--sysconfdir** parameter, The completion script  can not be installed for all users.
   *If you omit the --sysconfdir option , the configuration file will be installed in /usr/local/etc*
2. strange characters

   check if the default shell is working fine

   echo $SHELL

the values ​​can be **/bin/bash** or **/bin/sh**, or at least they are the most common.

check the user's shell, outside the container, because these values ​​are passed when the container is displayed.

Now, terminal represents the raw keycode of the keys sent to it by the keyboard, and shell would normally intercept the keypress; 
but for some reason they are directly printing the value of the modifier keys.

from the bash manual for special characters,  what does ^[[A mean?

> \[     begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be
>   used to embed
>          a terminal control sequence into the prompt

terminal control sequence refiere to special keys ( Ctrl, Alt, Win, ... ) modifiers. In other words, [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).
then **^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C** are cursor-down, cursor-up, cursor-left, cursor-right 
*and these are shown because you combine the cursor keys with modifier keys*.

At this point I can not give you a clear solution for lack of detail in the information you provide.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you take a look again? The question was unclear due to a formatting error.